# How can I add a "new item" link to the bottom of a CQWP

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part

I assume its the itemStyle.xsl that I need to customize, but what is the code to add a "new Item Link to the bottom of a Content Query Web Part that takes you to the modalDialog for a new list item?

Bismarck

Answer (score 0):

The CQWP is tricky because it might roll-up content from multiple sites, sub-sites and lists, which practically means that items could be mixed comming from different lists, therefore your URL will change everytime. The obvious question will be - New item to be added into which list, under which site?

Cannot deliver full code but
 - link to the NewForm.aspx - for which you need to know the URL of the item to deduct the ListItem or at least you would need the List Id

```
function Opendialog() {
       var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
       options.resizable = 1;
       options.scroll = 1;
       options.url = YourSiteURL + "/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=8&ListId={PUT-LIST-GUID-HERE}";
       options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback);
       SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
   }
```